# How to take screen shot using Sikuli?

Tags: automation, sikuli

I need to use Sikuli for automation but I am unable to take screenshots. The problem is that when I click on "Take Screenshot" or "Create Region" the IDE gets hidden but selecting area option does not appear....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are using Java 6 not 7. If you try to run both on the same computer, make sure to take a look in the `system32` folder. Because Java 7 copies `java.exe` and `javaw.exe` there. You have to delete/rename them.

**Better Solution:** Uninstall Java 7 and install Java 6. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall JDK, which ever version you have, I too faced the same problem, but after uninstalling JDK, it was working well